# Add custom text to Page Tamplate without need to know html

Tags: wp-admin

I am new to wordpress. I have experience in css \ html \ js and asp.net (and also a bit of php now).

I've added to my blog certain areas that are hard coded in html and css. In these areas I'd like to be able to set text based on the admin's input in the panel's page.

I want a person who doesn't know html to be able to easily change the content of these hard coded areas.

How can this be done?

Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have two solutions for this:

1. Use [Custom Fields](http://codex.wordpress.org/Custom_Fields) This is a very comprehensive guide: [The Power of WordPress Custom Fields](http://wparena.com/how-to/the-power-of-wordpress-custom-fields/). There are some very useful plugins like [Custom Field Template](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/custom-field-template/) and [Magic Fields](http://wparena.com/how-to/the-power-of-wordpress-custom-fields/) which use them.
2. Use [Widgets](http://codex.wordpress.org/WordPress_Widgets). The [Widgets API](http://codex.wordpress.org/Widgets_API) allows you to easily build your own widgets.

Answer (score 2):

you can create more widgets for your theme and then display the content of theme where you want. Look at this page: http://codex.wordpress.org/Widgetizing_Themes

Comment: good comment, though sorich's was the best, therefore marked as answer. thank you